# ImportError: cannot import name 'speech' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-speech-api

i installed `google.cloud` for the system using `pip install google-cloud`.

but next error i have `ImportError: cannot import name 'speech' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`

how to correct this error?

Comment: ‘pip install google-cloud-speech‘

Comment: You can also make sure you installed it for the correct python version.  I initially did `python -m pip install google-cloud-speech` but needed to do `python3 -m pip install google-cloud-speech`

Answer (score 15):

```
pip install google-cloud-speech
```

This solved the error for me